# Substitution does not work while substituting with a value from list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I am writing a program which iteratively solve and make substitution from a list. As I have shown in the code substitution works when I enter the value directly (**Input 100**). When I extract the same value from a list and substitute (**102**),It does not seem to work. I have checked the FullForm for both and they are same.

```
x''[t] /. x -> Function[{t}, A Cos[t]]

(* -A Cos[t] *)

xsol[[1]]

(* A Cos[t] *)

x''[t] /. x -> Function[{t}, xsol[[1]]]    

(* 0 *)
```

I am new to Mathematica. Could someone please explain the right method to do it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please precisely specify `xsol[[1]]`.

Comment: Try `x''[t] /. x -> Function[{t}, Evaluate@xsol[[1]]]`

Comment: @Nasser Thanks it worked.

Comment: The reason that `Evaluate` is needed is that `Function` has attribute `HoldAll`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks,I will check the documentation